# Haskell: How lazy is the lazy `Control.Monad.ST.Lazy` monad?

Tags: haskell

I have been experimenting with the strict and lazy `ST` monads, and I do not understand clearly the degree of laziness of each.
For example, using the lazy `Control.Monad.State.Lazy` monad we can write:

```
main = print $ (flip evalState) "a" $ do
    forever $ put "b"
    put "c"
    get
```

This works fine and outputs `"c"`. Dually, the same code for the strict `Control.Monad.State.Strict` variant will run `put "b"` forever, and hang.

Intuitively, I would expect the same duality to hold for the `ST` monads. That is, given the code:

```
main = print $ S.runST $ do
        r <- newSTRef "a"
        forever $ writeSTRef r "b"
        writeSTRef r "c"
        readSTRef r
```

`Control.Monad.ST.Lazy` should output `"c"`, while `Control.Monad.ST.Strict` should hang. However, they both loop indefinitely. I believe that there is a valid reason for this, like: reading *backwards*, the reference `r` is not yet allocated at the time that the last `writeSTRef` is called. But it somehow feels like we could do better.

Comment: You could use `Control.Monad.Lazy.Unsafe.unsafeInterleaveST $ forever $ writeSTRef r "b"` to get the laziness you're looking for.  Without knowing more about your problem though, I can't say if doing so is actually safe.

Comment: Yes, that was the *solution* that I found. @luqui has also been commenting on this on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068399/haskell-performance-of-iorefs/24071781#24071781](another thread). `forever` was kind of an exaggeration, because it seems like you at least need to trace the history of modifications backwards (not evaluating the ones over the same reference I hope) to the point of creation.

Comment: Oh I should point out that `unsafeInterleaveST` means to defer evaluation of its argument until the result value is needed.  Which means if you ignore the result of `unsafeInterleaveST` (as in my comment), you may as well just delete that line.  `unsafeInterleave*` functions are really meant for creating codata such as lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How lazy is the lazy `Control.Monad.ST.Lazy` monad?

Surprisingly, it is perfectly lazy. But `Data.STRef.Lazy` isn't.

#### `ST.Lazy` *is* lazy

Lets focus on another example for a second:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.ST as S
import qualified Control.Monad.ST.Lazy as L

squared :: Monad m => m [Integer]
squared = mapM (return . (^2)) [1..]

ok, oops :: [Integer]
ok   = L.runST squared
oops = S.runST squared
```

Even though `ok` and `oops` should do the same, we can get only the elements of `ok`. If we would try to use `head oops`, we would fail. However, concerning `ok`, we can take arbitrarily many elements.

Or, to compare them to the non-monadic squared list, they behave like:

```
ok, oops :: [Integer]
ok'   = map (^2) [1..]
oops' = let x = map (^2) [1..] in force x -- Control.DeepSeq.force
```

That's because the strict version evaluates all state operations, even though they're not required for our result. On the other hand, the lazy version delays the operations:

> This module presents an identical interface to Control.Monad.ST, except that the monad delays evaluation of state operations until a value depending on them is required.

#### What about `readSTRef`?

Now lets focus again on your example. Note that we can get an infinite loop with even simpler code:

```
main = print $ L.runST $ do
    forever $ return ()
    r <- newSTRef "a"
    readSTRef r
```

If we add an additional `return` at the end …

```
main = print $ L.runST $ do
    forever $ return ()
    r <- newSTRef "a"
    readSTRef r
    return "a"
```

… everything is fine. So apparently there's something strict in `newSTRef` or `readSTRef`. Lets have a look at their [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-STRef-Lazy.html#readSTRef):

```
import qualified Data.STRef as ST

newSTRef        = strictToLazyST . ST.newSTRef
readSTRef       = strictToLazyST . ST.readSTRef
writeSTRef  r a = strictToLazyST (ST.writeSTRef r a)
```

And there's the culprit. `Data.STRef.Lazy` is actually implemented via `Data.STRef`, which is meant for `Control.Monad.ST.Strict`. [`strictToLazyST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Lazy.html#v:strictToLazyST) only hides this detail:

> ```
> strictToLazyST :: ST.ST s a -> ST s a
> strictToLazyST m = ST $ \s ->
> ```
>
> Convert a strict ST computation into a lazy one. The strict state thread passed to `strictToLazyST` is not performed until the result of the lazy state thread it returns is demanded.

Now lets put things together:

- in `main`, we want to `print` the value given by the lazy `ST` computation
- the lazy `ST` computation's value is given by a lazy `readSTRef`
- the lazy `readSTRef` is actually implemented as a lazy wrapper around the strict `readSTRef`
- the strict `readSTRef` evaluates the state as if it was a strict one
- the strict evaluation of `forever $ return ()` bites us

So the current `ST.Lazy` is lazy enough. **It's the `Data.STRef.Lazy` that's too strict.** As long as `Data.STRef.Lazy` is based on `strictToLazyST`, this behavior will endure.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, it checks out. From the previous discussions it seems like `Data.STRef` is *stricter* for a reason.

Comment: I would even risk saying that is is impossible for it to be fully lazy in general, because unlike the plain old `State` monad for which allocation is performed by `runState`, and therefore everything before a `State.put` can be ignored, it needs to dynamically allocate new space for each `newSTRef`. There is a possible optimization that comes to mind, however: for `STRef`s over different types, the `newSTRef`, `readSTRef`, `writeSTRef` operations could be lazily interleaved.

Comment: @hpacheco: Concerning `State`: It doesn't get ignored per se, but instead uses an irrefutable pattern which makes it just lazy enough so that we can have that effect. An operation on `STRef` on the other hand changes the state, either the `RealWorld`, or the thread of execution `s`. That's deeply implemented in `read|new|write|modifyMutVar`. A _real_ lazy `STRef` would need to collect actions and then collaps them after the total actions have been parsed. Whether this is possible without `unsafeInterleaveST`, I don't know. I'm still pretty new to Haskell :).